# No encuentro el error a mi código en R, al copilar no arroja los resultados esperados

Tags: r

El siguiente código es de una regresión utilizando una distribución beta, corre normal pero no da los resultados esperados y no encuentro el error.

```
 gmodel.ZOB<- 'model{                                                                  Cte <- 10000                                                                            
for(j in 1:n) { fdBeta[j]<- exp(loggam(a1[j]+a2[j])-loggam(a1[j])-loggam(a2[j])+(a1[j]-1)*log(Mortalrate[j])+(a2[j]-1)*log(1-Mortalrate[j]))                            a1[j]<- mu[j]*phi                                                                           a2[j]<- (1-mu[j])*phi  logit(mu1[j]) <-sum(beta[1:P]*X1[j,1:P])                         
mu[j]<- max(0.00001,min(0.9999,mu1[j]))                                          
fdBetaInf[j]  <- fdBeta[j]                                                               q[j]<- fdBetaInf[j]/Cte                                                                    q1[j]<-max(0.00001,min(0.99999,q[j]))                                                 ones[j]~ dbern(q1[j])}                                                                    for (p in 1:P) {beta[p]~dnorm(0, 0.001) } phi~dunif(0, 10)}                             datas <- list(X1= X1, n = n, Mortalrate=Mortalrate, P =ncol(X1)) inits <- function () { list(beta = rep(0, ncol(X1)), phi = 1)}param <- c("beta", "phi") model.out<-run.jags(model=model.ZOB,monitor= param,data= datas,inits=inits,n.chains=2,sample=10000,adapt=5000,burnin=5000,thin=20,modules='runjags',jags.refresh=40)
print(model.out)
```

Comment: ¡Hola! Revisa el código que has escrito e intenta ponerlo de una forma más legible para que se pueda analizar. Como ves, se aprecia verde el texto, ¿tienes bien puestos los signos "`" ?